# Compressed data in Spring Data Rest project

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-rest

I would like to compress / decompress field content while performing CRUD operation in order to keep the database (currently mysqlDB) as small as possible.
Thanks.

Comment: What data are you persisting? Can you elaborate on why / where you have this requirement?

Comment: I have different xml data, describing a book record, such as metadata, text, word coordinates, etc. I pass it to my small Spring Data Rest application in order to use it in other projects. So, I have to compress data for each field separatly (metadata, coordinates)

Comment: by creating/updating and decompress by reading. Currently an additional controller is used to supply a content per field as xml.

Comment: That's not really your application's concern. The database is responsible for storing data (sic!) and if you want compression then set it up accordingly.

Comment: You shouldn't be attempting to compress content in the database yourself, as was suggested above, but you can compress content for transport in the http response to reduce bandwidth. I think Spring has a mechanism to turn on gzip compression at the http level.